# VB.NET SHA-1 how to produce HASH or fingerprint of a software

Tags: vb.net, sha1

Apologies in advance for asking these questions if they appear to be silly:

1. How can I produce a fingerprint or hash of a software (.net win app)
   using SHA-1 (160 bit)?
2. When we talk about bits, what does it mean when we say 160 bit
   SHA-1? How salt helps in making it more secure?
3. Is there any utility that I can include
   in my software to implement this?
4. What would be the best place to store hash in order to test the integrity of the software
   by comparing the files' hash against this stored hash

Comment: It seems either I put a very difficult question to answer or a very silly one, as I'm only getting views to my questions even after 5 days but no answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting "no response" from anyone I tried and got the following answers:
1) & 2)
In cryptography, SHA-1 is a cryptographic hash function designed by the United States National Security Agency and is a U.S. Federal Information Processing Standard published by the United States NIST. SHA-1 produces a 160-bit hash value (from Wikipedia)

SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value. A SHA-1 hash value is typically rendered as a hexadecimal number, 40 digits long.

SHA stands for "secure hash algorithm".

SHA-1 when mixed up with a "secret key" results in HMAC-SHA1 which is more secure than SHA1.

3) No utility is needed as we can use the Microsoft's HMACSHA1 class to generate our encrypted code.

4) I created a utility to which requires a file as an input and generates HMACSHA1 for that file. Upon generating the HMACSHA1 for the files, we can store that values in app.config file with filename as the key. Whenever your software runs, it will use the same secret key to produce HMACSHA1 for the files in app.config, compares the it's own hash with the values stored in app.config by doing a byte comparison. If the values are same, it means that the software is verified else you can quit the software by displaying appropriate message.